# Change color of button without leaving page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

This allows me to change the category of photos without leaving the page. IT WORKS.

Next step - The pre-defined category of a photo has a button with a green background and the other two have red. When making a new choice I want the pressed button to turn green and the other two buttons for that photo to turn to/stay red. The green css is c_on and the red css is c_off.

How can I set the right css to the right button with javascript/ajax/jquery?

Any help greatly appreciated. (Styles are defined correctly in my code but I could not get it to paste here properly so I used a comment).

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "test_ajax_update_code.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.c_on {color: #000;background-color:#F00;}
.c_off {color: #000;background-color:#0F0;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="myfoto1.jpg" width="500" height="333" border="0"><br>
            <form id="form1">
            <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1373" >
            <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="1" >
            <input type="submit" value="1" class="c_on">
            </form>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form id="form2">
            <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1373" >
            <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="2" >
            <input type="submit" value="2" class="c_off">
            </form>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form id="form3">
            <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1373" >
            <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="3" >
            <input type="submit" value="3" class="c_off">
            </form>
        <img src="myfoto2.jpg" width="500" height="333" border="0"><br>
            <form id="form1">
            <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1374" >
            <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="1" >
            <input type="submit" value="1" class="c_off">
            </form>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form id="form2">
            <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1374" >
            <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="2" >
            <input type="submit" value="2" class="c_on">
            </form>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <form id="form3">
            <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1374" >
            <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="3" >
            <input type="submit" value="3" class="c_off">
            </form>
```

Comment: you could use :visited in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
// set all buttons to c_off
$('input[type="submit"]').removeClass('c_on').addClass('c_off');

// set the submitted one to c_on
$(this).find('input[type="submit"]').removeClass('c_off').addClass('c_on');
```

This would make your code look as follows:

```
$(function () {
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "test_ajax_update_code.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
    });

    // set all buttons to c_off
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeClass('c_on').addClass('c_off');

    // set the submitted one to c_on
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').removeClass('c_off').addClass('c_on');

    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Nearly there. But it changes all the green buttons to red even the ones on other photos that have already been pressed. Every photo has 3 buttons to designate 3 categories and a pressed green button should stay green unless another button under that photo is pressed.
In it's simplest form this is my page
http://garryjones.se/test/test_ajax_update.php
Can I group sets of three forms together? Or how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand exactly what you mean, but with a couple of events and booleans you should probably be able to do something like this fairly easy.

```
var image_1 = false

if (image_1 === true) {
    //change button styles
}

var element = getElement('div.image') // example

element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    image_1 = true'
}
```

And the wouldn't even be any ajax involved. For example you could submit when all are true.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do:
Every photo has 3 buttons to designate 3 categories and a pressed green button should stay green unless another button under that photo is pressed. In it's simplest form this is my page garryjones.se/test/test_ajax_update.php Can I group sets of three forms together? Or how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$('input:submit').on('click',function(){
   $('input:submit').removeClass('c_on').addClass('c_off');
   $(this).removeClass('c_off').addClass('c_on');
})
```

Comment: Nearly there. But it changes all the green buttons to red even the ones on other photos that have already been pressed. Every photo has 3 buttons to designate 3 categories and a pressed green button should stay green unless another button under that photo is pressed. In it's simplest form this is my page garryjones.se/test/test_ajax_update.php Can I group sets of three forms together? Or how is this done? –

Comment: you could have a common parent `div#parent` for each group and change the code as `$('input:submit',this.parent('div#parentid')).removeClass('c_on').addClass('c_off')`

Answer (score 0):

You should add a click event for each button, which allow you to remove any `.c_on` class, and apply it to the clicked button.

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
    $(".c_on").removeClass('c_on').addClass('c_off');
    $(this).removeClass('c_off').addClass('c_on');
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution and check the`CSS` for appropriate color to the class.

**UPDATE:**

1. `id` must be unique. Hence I have changed the `id` of the `forms` to `class`.
2. Then I have added new `data-image` property to differentiate the set of buttons.

**Updated Code snippets:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "test_ajax_update_code.php",
      data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
    });
    var clicked = $(this),
      imageName = clicked.data("image");
    clicked.removeClass("c_off").addClass("c_on");
    $('input[type="submit"]').each(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      if (!clicked.is(self)) {
        if (self.hasClass("c_on") && imageName == self.data("image"))
          self.removeClass("c_on").addClass("c_off");
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.c_off {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #F00;
}
.c_on {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="myfoto1.jpg" width="500" height="333" border="0">
<br>
<form class="form1">
  <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1373">
  <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="1" class="c_on" data-image="img1">
</form>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form class="form2">
  <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1373">
  <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="2">
  <input type="submit" value="2" class="c_off" data-image="img1">
</form>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form class="form3">
  <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1373">
  <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="3">
  <input type="submit" value="3" class="c_off" data-image="img1">
</form>
<img src="myfoto2.jpg" width="500" height="333" border="0">
<br>
<form class="form1">
  <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1374">
  <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="1" class="c_off" data-image="img2">
</form>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form class="form2">
  <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1374">
  <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="2">
  <input type="submit" value="2" class="c_on" data-image="img2">
</form>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form class="form3">
  <input name="num" type="hidden" value="1374">
  <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="3">
  <input type="submit" value="3" class="c_off" data-image="img2">
</form>
```

Comment: Nearly there. But it changes all the green buttons to red even the ones on other photos that have already been pressed. Every photo has 3 buttons to designate 3 categories and a pressed green button should stay green unless another button under that photo is pressed. In it's simplest form this is my page garryjones.se/test/test_ajax_update.php Can I group sets of three forms together? Or how is this done? –

Comment: Thanks. Very close now. The php code that actually updates the database does not work in the latest version although the button behaviour is exactly what I want. I can't see what is preventing the php code from firing.
2 versions on my server
1) php firing, incorrect button behaviour, 
http://garryjones.se/test/test_ajax_update.php
2) php NOT firing, correct button behaviour 
http://garryjones.se/test/test_ajax_update_new.php

Comment: What do you mean by **"button behaviour"** here?

Comment: In the latest the submit buttons are treated in groups so when one is clicked it goes green and JUST the other green one in the group goes red. However when the code to make this happen is added in the script tag the previously working script that triggers test_ajax_update_code.php ceases to work. In the previous attempt the php code was triggered correctly but ALL the green buttons went red (even the ones in other "sets" of forms). Your latest addition fixed that so the buttons behave as I want, I just need the button to also run the php script.

Comment: It just needed data: $(this).parent().serialize(), in place of data: $(this).serialize(), so now it's working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay. Accept this answer if it is helped you to solve your problem. To accept this as an answer click the tick mark that is below the down arrow of my answer.